# Laravel - How to order by a related attribute in hasMany

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two entities: *Producers* and *Protocols*. Producers has many Protocols.

**Problem**

Select all producers ordered by their last protocol creation date.

**Solution**

In order to get this, I tried:

```
$producers = Producer::join('protocol', 'protocol.producer_id', '=', 'producer.id')
  ->orderBy('protocol.created_at', 'desc');
```

But just didn't work as expected mainly because I even limited the last protocol. How can I achieve this using Laravel Eloquent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupBy()`:

```
$producers = Producer::select('producer.*')
    ->join('protocol', 'protocol.producer_id', '=', 'producer.id')
    ->groupBy('producer.id')
    ->orderByRaw('max(protocol.created_at) desc');
```

Answer (score 0):

first at all describe a relationship for last protocol on Producer model

```
public function last_protocol(){
    return $this->hasOne(Protocol::class)->latest();
}
```

then, in your controller

```
$producers = Producer::with('last_protocol')->get()->sortByDesc('last_protocol.created_at');
```

Comment: The solution needs to be with Eloquent not Collection.